# Docker React Not Copying Files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I am currently building an app with ReactJS on FE, Express on the backend, and using docker. I am having an issue where my package.json is not being found for my node server in docker. The error message is as follows:

```
server_1    | [0] 
server_1    | [0] > stocklookback@1.0.0 server /code/app/server
server_1    | [0] > nodemon index.js
server_1    | [0] 
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! path /code/app/client/package.json
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! code ENOENT
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! errno -2
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! syscall open
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/code/app/client/package.json'
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! enoent 
server_1    | [1] 
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
server_1    | [1] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-08-04T20_53_24_266Z-debug.log
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! errno 254
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! stocklookback@1.0.0 client: `npm start --prefix ../client`
server_1    | npm ERR! Exit status 254
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! 
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! Failed at the stocklookback@1.0.0 client script.
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
server_1    | [1] 
stocklookback_client_1 exited with code 1
```

Now my docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '3.3'

volumes:
  postgres_database :
     external: false

services:
 server:
   build: ./server
   expose:
     - ${APP_SERVER_PORT}
   environment:
     API_HOST: ${API_HOST}
     APP_SERVER_PORT: ${APP_SERVER_PORT}
   ports:
     - ${APP_SERVER_PORT}:${APP_SERVER_PORT}
   volumes:
     - ./server:/code/app/server/src
   command: npm run dev
```

And my Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /code/app/server/
WORKDIR /code/app/server/

COPY package.json /code/app/server/
COPY package-lock.json /code/app/server/

RUN npm install

COPY . /code/app/server/

CMD [ "npm", "start", "dev" ]
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the logs carefully it's not your server that's giving you the issue of `package.json` not found, **it's actually your client**.

Surprised?
In the logs you can see,

```
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! path /code/app/client/package.json
```

See, the path is `/code/app/client/package.json`.

```
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/code/app/client/package.json'
```

This unexpected turn of events is because you are executing the npm script `npm start --prefix ../client` as evidenced by,

```
server_1    | [1] npm ERR! stocklookback@1.0.0 client: `npm start --prefix ../client`
```

Running `npm start --prefix ../client` will try to look for a `package.json` given by the relative path `../client` and try to execute `npm start` for the `package.json` in that path but it will fail with file not found.

**Now your question may be how is that script being run?**

In your Docker compose file you are executing the command `npm run dev` which, bear in mind, will override the `npm start dev` given in your Dockerfile.
Check your `npm run dev` script in your server's `package.json`. Is it somehow calling that script, `npm start --prefix ../client`?

I am pretty sure it is because this app is clearly a fullstack react+express app. So I assume your `npm run dev` script is attempting to start both the backend and the frontend. However since your Docker container only has the server code it fails.